# Можно ли указывать моделям pydant'ика параметры, используя paginate?

Tags: python, pagination, fastapi, pydantic

У меня есть простая функция, которая должна выдавать пользователям несколько новостей:

```
@router.get('/all', response_model=LimitOffsetPage[NewsRead])
async def get_all_news(limit: int = Query(default=50, lt=101, gt=0),
                       offset: int = Query(default=0, gt=-1),
                       session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    params = LimitOffsetParams(limit=limit, offset=offset)
    request = select(News).options(
        selectinload(News.comments),
        selectinload(News.author),
        selectinload(News.comments, Comment.author),
    ).order_by(desc(News.created_at))

    return await paginate(session, request, params=params)
```

где **NewsRead** - это модель pydantic'а

```
class NewsRead(BaseModel):
    id: int

    title: str
    context: str

    rating_value: int

    author: UserShortRead
    comments: List[CommentShortRead]

    created_at: datetime.datetime
    updated_at: datetime.datetime

    file: Optional[FileRead]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Дело в том, что параметра **rating_value** я высчитывал и добавлял. Например:

```
news.rating_value = await get_news_rating(session=session, news=news)
```

Аналогично я поступаю, для передачи контента файла. Сначала создаю экземпляр класса pydantic'а **FileRead**, заполняю его, а потом передаю, как параметр объекта, который в будущем будет передан в NewsRead.from_orm(**some_object**)

Например:

```
if news.filepath:
    try:
        with open(news.filepath, 'rb') as file_content:
            file = FileRead(filetype=get_settings().IMAGE_CONTROLLER.file_format,
                            content=base64.b64encode(file_content.read()))

        news.file = file
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise HTTPException(500, detail='server miss news files')
return NewsRead.from_orm(news)
```

Однако, когда я хочу использовать pagination и делаю так:

```
@router.get('/all', response_model=LimitOffsetPage[NewsRead])
async def get_all_news(limit: int = Query(default=50, lt=101, gt=0),
                       offset: int = Query(default=0, gt=-1),
                       session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    params = LimitOffsetParams(limit=limit, offset=offset)
    request = select(News).options(
        selectinload(News.comments),
        selectinload(News.author),
        selectinload(News.comments, Comment.author),
    ).order_by(desc(News.created_at))

    return await paginate(session, request, params=params)
```

То, очевидно, paginate не прочитает мои мысли и не возьмет недостающие параметры из неоткуда. Как мне сообщить ему эти параметры?

Comment: Недостающие параметры - это какие?

Comment: @insolor, недостающие параметры - это **rating_value** и **file**, которые я вручную указывал, как показано выше.

Comment: Как я понимаю, по сути вам нужно циклом пройти по результатам запроса и проставить значения. Можно это сделать после функции paginate, просто не передавать результат сразу в return, а сохранить в переменную ее результат, по результату пройтись "циклом", потом дозаполненный результат уже возвращать через return. P.S. это сейчас из головы придумал. Вообще, нужно смотреть что за объект LimitOffsetPage, и как к его содержимому обратиться.

Comment: @insolor, хорошая идея. Однако это невозможно из-за ошибки, которая вызывается внутри paginate.

`File "C:\Users\Азя\PycharmProjects\LoS\routers\news.py", line 76, in get_all_news
    data = await paginate(session, request, params=params)
...
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for LimitOffsetPage[NewsRead]
items -> 0 -> rating_value
  field required (type=value_error.missing)`
Как я уже и сказал, внутри paginate происходит ошибка, которая сообщает об отсутствии данных у соответствующих полей

Comment: Сделайте дозаполняемые поля Optional.

Comment: @insolor, это сработало. Спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: Здравствуйте @incolor, возникла ещё одна проблема. SQL модель News содержит поле file_url. Однако, **paginate** возвращает модели pydantic'а, а не SQL. Соответственно, доступ к полю file_url получить не получается. Я вижу возможные решения, но они мне не нравятся. Во-первых можно запросить соответствующие данные из бд, но тогда мы получим в 2 раза больше одинаковых запросов. Так же можно создать поле в классе pydantic'а, взять из него данные и удалить, но это скорее выглядит как костыль

Comment: Насколько я вижу [по исходникам](https://github.com/uriyyo/fastapi-pagination/blob/main/fastapi_pagination/paginator.py), paginate как раз возвращает исходный тип (у вас это News). Он в общем-то не может ничего знать NewsRead, указанный декораторе функции. Так что по идее не должно быть никаких проблем с доступом к полям SQL модели. Если все-таки не получается, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @insolor, к сожалению, он как раз таки возвращает list из NewsRead. Возможно, он получает доступ к типу данных в декораторе с помощью функции **add_pagination(app)**, которая прописывается в main функции. Я создам отдельный вопрос. Спасибо за вашу помощь